# Displaying the name instead of ID in DetailView Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to display the name instead of ID in the DetailView.

I have done similar on what I did in the GridView which is:

```
[
     'attribute' => 'employee_id',
     'value' => 'employee.employee_name'
],
```

But if I try it on DetailView it displays "employee.employee_name" not the Employee Name

Here's my model:

```
public function getEmployee()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Employee::className(), ['id' => 'employee_id']);
}
```

Comment: for 'employee.employee_name', it should be ok, but you must clarify for the relationship name in master model.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found the answer I have just read the Yii2 documentation.

The solution is

```
[
       'attribute' => 'employee_id',
       'value' => $model->employee->employee_name,
],
```

I hope this also help the others.

Comment: You should check if `employee` returns object, otherwise error can occure here. Change value to `$model->employee ? $model->employee->employee_name : null`.

Comment: Why would I null it?

Comment: It will display `(not set)` in your `DetailView` or `GridView`.

Comment: Propably because your `employee_name` is empty, but if relation fails, you will get exception `Trying to get property of non-object`, because `$model->employee` will be null.

Answer (score 0):

There is even more simpler one line solution

```
[
   'attribute' => 'employee.employee_name'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In GridView, you can show the name using the "employee.employee_name" approach.

But "DetailView" Approach is different. You must use the $model approach, which is shown below.

```
$model->your_relation_name(without prefixing "action")->field_name

//e.g.
[
'attribute'=> 'Employee Name',
'value'=>$model->employee->employee_name;
]
```